# Apps management dashboard: what features would you like to see in it?

Tags: web-applications, system-administration, saas, dashboard

On a dashboard to manage **business web apps** (CRM, email marketing, collaboration, accounting...) from a single place which features should be a must have and nice to have?

Those that come to mind are SSO, unified billing, users provisioning. What else?

What should be available to the super user (admin) vs the business user?

Do you know any products of this kind in the market today?

Comment: Marketing surveys are best left to websites that handle those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you touch here the main points to start with but the challenge is actually to really address all the needs inside each of those functions:

- SSO is a whole world in itself and enabling this will vary from customer to customers. So do plan to include support for a wide range of SSO technology (SAML for the enterprise, OpenID/Oauth for public wide access, etc,..)
- User management is also a critical one (provisioning, de-provisioning, Role management, Delegation, etc,..) Again the list of features needed in this space is pretty long..